# rectangular image responsive in different screen size

Tags: html, css

I have an image which its size is 1050x700. I would place it in full screen when it is in desktop. the idea would be to place it when is in desktop version under the black bar in this way the image remain almost the same.
here it is the jsfiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/qLdp4czn/1/

in the mobile there is no problem because it fit the device display so it should back normal without placing it under the bar

here is the code:

```
<div class="container-fluid top-bar">
    <div class="row-top">
        <div id="central-block" class="text-center">
            <p>Title</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="img-background">
    <img src="http://ppcdn.500px.org/75961441/84f7332982b9c76296fef33b528c7d6ddd22e5a0/5.jpg" alt="animal" class="img-responsive">
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear, please explain your desired result....EDIT oh I see, you want this to be full width? http://jsfiddle.net/qLdp4czn/1/embedded/result/

Comment: yes exactly. the idea would be to put one chunk under the nav bar in the desktop version of the site

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6758338/how-to-have-a-non-fixed-fullscreen-background-image

Answer (score 0):

Put the image as a background-image instead and remove the img element:

```
.img-background {
 background-image:url(http://ppcdn.500px.org/75961441/84f7332982b9c76296fef33b528c7d6ddd22e5a0/5.jpg);
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
 background-size:100% auto;
 position:relative;
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
```

You might have to set the width and height of the element depending on your other CSS.

Comment: I get white because the img-background is empty

Comment: Ok now works I have set the width and height of img-background but unfortunately I got scrolling

Comment: Ok I fix it. I have placed img-background as the parent of everyone.

Comment: It works pretty fine in desktop version but in mobile I would get the image not under the black bar

Comment: @Mazzy Put a negative z-index to it if you want everything to go on top of the background image...

Comment: I have placed a zindex positive on the navbar and this works for the desktop. I would not have zindex in the mobile in this way in the mobile the img is totally showed

Comment: I have a problem in mobile version. the image goes under the navbar and I don't know how to avoid this problem

Comment: I have placed the image inside img-background. I got scroll. it works responsive but  I wouldn't get scroll